# asp.net core unobtrusive form validation callback for remote validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I have login form with 2 fields (daaaa ;D) email and password ...
Password field is hidden initially and I need to check the email by a remote validator and show the password field if email is valid ...

`[Remote("ValidateAccount", "Account", ErrorMessage = "I couldn’t find any matching account!")]`

The  validator itself works and makes http get requests to server and validates the email and shows the error message ...

But I cant detect when this validation is finished so I can show the password field ...

I tried to override validators `showErrors` function, but it gets fired with empty errors before the remote validator is finished ...

I tried `$( '#form' ).on( "invalid-form.validate", console.log );` but this only gets triggered when form is submitted. same goes for `invalidHandler` ...

So I can think of only 2 options :
1- using `setTimeout` to check the fields error messages!!
2- writing my own custom logic for the remote validator

So is there any other option?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could also use `DOMCharacterDataModified` event to check if the span for error message have changed. Here is a working demo like below:

```
@model Testdata
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" id="EmailMessage"class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" hidden />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $('#EmailMessage').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
            var input = $("#Email").hasClass("valid");
            if (input) {
                $("#Password").removeAttr("hidden");
            }
            else {
                $("#Password").attr("hidden","hidden");
            }
    })
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this won't work for remote validator, the error span will be empty while remote validation is running

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with this code

```
  var loginForm = $('#login-form')[0];
    var settings = $.data(loginForm, 'validator').settings;
    var oldSucessFunction = settings.success;

    settings.success = function (error, element) {
      //Do something here
      oldSucessFunction(error, element);
      if (emailInput[0] === element) {
        enableButton(nextButton);
      } else if (passwordInput[0] === element) {
        enableButton(submitButton);
      }
    }
```